# Migrating from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 issue (@RunWith to @ExtendWith)

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit5

I am trying to convert the test-code of a Spring Boot controller from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5. I almost replaced all the annotations of JUnit 4 with JUnit 5 but got some issue when tried to replace `@RunWith` with `@ExtendWith`.

```java
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @WebMvcTest(value = HappyPostController.class, secure = false)
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    public class HappyPostControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Mock
        private HappyPostServiceImpl happyPostService;

        @InjectMocks
        private HappyPostController happyPostController;

        @BeforeAll
        public void initialize() {
            happyPostController = new HappyPostController(happyPostService);
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                    .standaloneSetup(happyPostController)
                    .build();
        }

        @Test
        public void testMockCreation() {
            Assertions.assertNotNull(happyPostService);
            Assertions.assertNotNull(mockMvc);
        }

        //..... other test methods
}
```

The errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
......

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'happyPostController' defined in file [....\HappyPostController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rok.capp.service.HappyPostService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

.....

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rok.capp.service.HappyPostService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

........

```
Test ignored.
```

I tried to find the solution but failed. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to use @MockBean on the happyPostService field so it‘s added to the application context.

Comment: It works!!
But why @Mock doesn't work in Junit5 while it is working perfectly in Junit4?

Comment: I would have to see the exact code you were using with JUnit 4 in order to be able answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your JUnit 4 based version of that test class looked like, but the example you have provided is an unnecessary mixture of an integration test and a unit test.

You're using the `SpringExtension` to create an `ApplicationContext`, but then you never use the `ApplicationContext` or any other features from the *Spring TestContext Framework* or *Spring Boot Test*.

So, the best solution is simply to get rid of all of the unnecessary integration testing support and rewrite your test class as follows.

```java
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class HappyPostControllerTest {

    @Mock
    HappyPostServiceImpl happyPostService;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeAll
    void initialize() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        HappyPostController happyPostController = new HappyPostController(happyPostService);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(happyPostController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void testMockCreation() {
        assertNotNull(happyPostService);
        assertNotNull(mockMvc);
    }

    //..... other test methods
}
```

Regards,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

Comment: I have tried your way. 
https://pastebin.com/p0P5vMbv

This got NullPointerException at line 43 
happyPostService.savePost(happyPost);

Comment: Well, it's impossible to assist you without seeing the source code for `HappyPostService`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here : http://www.bytestree.com/spring/spring-boot-2-junit-5-rest-api-unit-testing/

Here it is updated to your case :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(HappyPostController.class)
class LotteryControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private HappyPostServiceImpl happyPostService;

    @Test
    public void should_get() throws Exception {
        // Given
        Mockito.when(happyPostService.whatevermethod()).thenReturn(someresult);
        // When
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/your_api"))
        // Then
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
```

using those dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
   <version>2.21.0</version>
 </dependency>
```